# NoMethodError with 'sign_in' using Devise::TestHelpers

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, rspec2

I'm trying to get Devise's helper methods to work for a controller spec.  Here's the relevant code:

```
# spec/spec_helper.rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  # other config stuff ...
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
end

#spec/controllers/posts_controller_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'

describe PostsController do

  describe "GET index" do

    admin = FactoryGirl.create(:admin)
    sign_in admin  # NoMethodError occurs
    it "does something..." do
    # etc etc etc
end
```

You have to be authenticated to render the template from this route, which is why I'm trying to sign in an admin so the test will pass. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the sign_in method must be used in a context of it or before blocks. Try:

```
before do
   admin = FactoryGirl.create(:admin)
   sign_in admin  # NoMethodError occurs
end
```

Comment: Weird... I'm doing this exact same thing and still getting the NoMethodError.  I swear this was working a few weeks ago...